# How to force emacs update frame title?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I customized variable `frame-title-format` to change frame title. However, Emacs only updates frame title when he/she wants to. Can I force Emacs to update (i.e. refresh) the title, say, after evaluating some custom functions?
Here is the frame-title-format:

```lisp
(setq frame-title-format "%b  %*  %n")
```

I want `%n` (display if narrowing) to take effect right after narrowing the buffer.

Comment: Witch operating system? Seems to work OK for Mac OS X.

Comment: +1 for "... when *he/she* wants to." :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way in elisp to force a redisplay is to use `(sit-for 0)`. You can define your own functions like the following:

```
(defun my-narrow-to-region (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (narrow-to-region start end)
  (sit-for 0))
```

**Note**: I can't verify that this solves your problem, as I use Mac OS X, where the frame title is properly updated even without this.

**Update**: In an earlier version of this answer I suggested using `defadvice`. I realized that this wasn't a good idea as it affects *all* uses of the function, as it gives rise to unwanted side effects.

Comment: Thanks a lot! (sit-for 0) works. I didn't know this command before. I am using Linux.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Basics.html

```
(force-mode-line-update)
```

also forces menu bar and frame title updates.

I can confirm that a frame title containing "%*" doesn't immediately update when I first modify a buffer and `(force-mode-line-update)` helps.
[emacs 24.5.1 on fedora 23 linux]

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why Emacs do not update may be this below. (<kbd>C-h v</kbd> frame-title-format)

`It is used only on frames for which no explicit name has been set`.

The first time I set it, it works. Then I use `modify-frame-parameters` to set a another name. It does not work. I use `modify-frame-parameters` tag frames and it works well.

You can use `modify-frame-parameters` to set the title instead.

```
(modify-frame-parameters nil
           (list (cons 'name string-name)))
```

But I can have not figure out how to set name based on parameter like `frame-title-format`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I am not sure either the parameter of modify-frame-parameters.